# XHTML Validation issue trying to render '&' character inside an ASP.Net control

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

Ok, the description is kind of funky, but here's my problem:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0">All Leads <i>(include Archive & Trash)</i></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="0">All Leads <i>(include Archive &amp; Trash)</i></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="All Leads <i>(include Archive & Trash)</i>" />
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="All Leads <i>(include Archive &amp; Trash)</i>" />
```

All three versions render the following html

```
All Leads <i>(include Archive & Trash)</i>
```

This of course fails XHTML validation. It needs to render the html like this:

```
All Leads <i>(include Archive &amp; Trash)</i>
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: So Asp.net is rendering your "&amp;" as "&" which then fails validation?

Have you tried the ( slightly ridiculous ) "&amp;amp;"?

Comment: That's RIDICULOUS!! But it worked. Enter it as an anwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you need to this &amp; as stupid as that is.